# Rule to validate a comma-separated field PLSQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm developing a procedure and stopped at the step to validate a field separated by commas.

I need to validate that in this field there are two records separated by commas, if it exists, update the field by removing the entry record and keeping the other one.
If there are more than 2 records, check which was the input record and validate if it is on the left or right side of the comma to perform the field update and keep the other records there.

I will demonstrate the field below:

```
        CONCIL
RECORDa,RECORDb,RECORDc
```

Here's what I've developed so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CANCEL (
    P_COD_MATRIZ INT,
    P_CONCIL IN TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL.COD_MATRIZ%TYPE,
    P_ID_CONCIL INT
)
IS  
    V_VIRGULA INT;
    V_RIGHT VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN 

    IF P_ID_CONCIL IS NOT NULL
    THEN
    DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_MBX WHERE ID_MBX = P_ID_CONCIL AND ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL 
        WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ);
    END IF;

    IF TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL.CD = 1 THEN
    DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_CD WHERE ID_CD = P_ID_CONCIL AND ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL 
        WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ);
    UPDATE TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL SET CD = 0 WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ;

    ELSIF TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_SFTP = 1 THEN
    DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_SFTP WHERE ID_SFTP = P_ID_CONCIL AND ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL 
        WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ);
    UPDATE TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL SET SFTP = 0 WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ;
    END IF;

    SELECT REGEXP_COUNT((SELECT TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL.CONCIL 
    FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL 
        WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ), ',') INTO V_VIRGULA FROM DUAL;

    IF V_VIRGULA = 0 THEN
    UPDATE TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL SET CONCIL = 'EC' WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ;
    END IF;

    SELECT 
    SUBSTR(TO_CHAR((SELECT TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL.CONCIL 
    FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL 
        WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ)), INSTR(TO_CHAR((SELECT TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL.CONCIL 
    FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL 
        WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ)), ',') +1) 
    INTO V_RIGHT FROM DUAL;

-- Here is the rule for validating the field separated by commas  

END;
/
```

**Remembering:**
The field can have up to three records.
And the record is removed as the **P_CONCIL** check-in is declared.

Manual routine:

```
DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_MBX where ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL           WHERE     COD_MATRIZ = '0000000000')   AND ID = '0000';
DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_SFTP         WHERE ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL  WHERE     COD_MATRIZ = '0000000000')   AND ID = '0000';
UPDATE TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL SET SFTP = 0      WHERE                                                         COD_MATRIZ = '0000000000';
UPDATE TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL SET CONCIL = 'EC' WHERE                                                         COD_MATRIZ = '0000000000';
SELECT ID, COD_MATRIZ, CONCIL, CD, SFTP FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL                                 WHERE     COD_MATRIZ = '0000000000';
SELECT * FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_MBX  where ID_PERFIL =  (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL       WHERE     COD_MATRIZ = '0000000000');
SELECT * FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_SFTP  where ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL       WHERE     COD_MATRIZ = '0000000000');
```

Thank you and I look forward to a great help!

Comment: If there are always going to be two fields then don't use a comma-delimited string in a single column; use two columns of the appropriate data type.

Comment: Okay, but it is the database administrator who defined the column.
I currently have nothing to do to create or change tables.

Comment: Can you (diplomatically) tell the DBA that they are wrong and using comma-delimited strings to store pairs of values is a recipe for complex and increasingly unmaintainable solutions which should be avoided if you can just put the same values into two columns with well defined data types. Keep-It-Simple!

Comment: I already tried and designed the solution for this type of infrastructure, but I still have no feedback.
I know what I requested is not a normal form of database but I need the momentary help to develop this rule to eliminate tasks that are being done manually and consequently eliminate errors.

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include: the DDL statements for the table you are updating; DML statements for some sample data that demonstrates each of the edge cases you need to handle; examples of how you would call the function for each of those edge cases and what your expected output would be. Its going to be much easier to try to work out what is going on if we don't have to reverse engineer your code and instead can work from the inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: We are using the DDL instruction to perform the "matrix cancellation" routine

Since, we have to consult BEFORE the three tables to get the table ID TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_SFTP and TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_MBX and check if the matrix "COD_MATRIZ" of the table TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL has more than one conciliator in the column "CONCIL".

Now think about when I need to perform this routine 50 to 60 times.

So I thought about the procedure, to minimize errors and eliminate time.

Comment: You keep posting more code; instead please [edit] your question and post **DATA**! What is the structure of your underlying tables? What values are in the rows of those tables? When you call the function what input values do you use? How do you expect the values in those tables to change (please describe this process in English and not via more code)? Please assume that we don't understand what you are talking about (because, most likely, we don't) and talking in just code (or about "matrix cancellations" or tables and columns you haven't described) is going to confuse us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with your code, since you didn't post before/after example data. And how are you calling this procedure?

But this should answer your question well enough for you to figure out the rest.

```
-- example data
create table TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL (concil varchar2(400));
insert into TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL values ('RECORDa,RECORDb,RECORDc');

declare
    v_left varchar2(100);
    v_center varchar2(100);
    v_right varchar2(100);
begin
    for r in (
      select level as lev, regexp_substr(TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL.CONCIL, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as val
      from TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL
      connect by level <= 3)
    loop
        if r.lev = 1 then
            v_left = r.val;
        elsif r.lev = 2 then
            v_center = r.val;
        elsif r.lev = 3 then
            v_right = r.val;
        end if;
    end loop;

    -- show variables
    dbms_output.print_line(v_left);
    dbms_output.print_line(v_center);
    dbms_output.print_line(v_right);
end;
/
```

If one of the values is blank, e.g. `RECORDa,,RECORDc`, then the corresponding variable (e.g. `v_center`) will be null.